# Anyone know the css or code to use to hide a div when VF set to contenttype/msword

Tags: visualforce, contenttype

I have tried

```
@media print{
    display: hidden;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;

}
```

Each time it displays a square block of text with the words {HIDDEN} in the word doc.

code I need to not output on print:

```
<apex:form styleClass="noprint">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!back_interview}" value="Back to Interview"/>
</apex:form>
```

Output In Word Doc:

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you are referring to ?

Comment: What happens when you remove  visibility:hidden  and display:hidden from your css? With visibility:hidden, there is a space allocated for it, just give display:none

Comment: @Prady - The code was for illustration. of what I have tried. I have tried each of those individually as well as every combination I could think of with the same results as above

Answer (score 1):

If your content type is going to be dynamic based on some variable, then why dont you use that itself to control the visibility of the div by wrapping it in an output panel?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountListClass" contentType="{!contentType}" cache="true">

<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!contentType != 'application/msWord#someDoc.doc'}">
<div>
........
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: While this would work it does not answer the question. I would prefer not to have controller code do the work that could possibly be done with CSS